# How to use polyfills in Microsoft Edge 44 or earlier?

Tags: javascript, web-component, polyfills, lit-element

I'm exploring what are polyfills and followed a youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSdAC8d5_Nw&t=379s) on using polyfills to show web components in unsupported browsers, specifically I'm targeting Microsoft Edge.

I have tried HTMLElements as the youtube video is showing and everything is working fine, however when I tried to do the same with LitElement, the component will not show in browsers even like Chrome.

I have created a Plunker file with the files that I'm currently working with at this link (http://plnkr.co/edit/w4np7dbm3N9yk1DFWA3W) Index.html is the webpage that I am trying to display all the components that I have created. The compoenents that I have are `<web-component></web-component>` and `<todo-view></todo-view>`.

The web-component is a HTMLElement defined in app.js whereare todo-view is a LitElement defined in todo-view.js.

In Microsoft Edge, I'm not getting any error messages but the todo-view component is not showing. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried document-register-element https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element?

Comment: Webkit based Edge or older Edge?

Comment: [Webkit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) is what drives Safari, Microsoft has chosen [Chromium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser)) for Edge. For now only [available for Windows 10 in the Dev Channel track](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/?platform=win10)

Comment: Sorry I wasn't up-to-date.. also [W7 and W8](https://venturebeat.com/2019/06/19/microsoft-launches-chromium-edge-builds-for-windows-7-and-windows-8/) since a few days..

Comment: Have you tried using the [Web components polyfill loader](https://github.com/webcomponents/polyfills/tree/master/packages/webcomponentsjs#using-webcomponents-loaderjs)? I can't test your code in edge right now but I somehow feel that might be the reason

Comment: @connexo I haven't and am currently looking at it, there are so many different customElements that I have seen online and it's alittle bit confusing

Comment: @evolutionxbox I trying on the following version of Edge, Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I understood that in Chromium the codes should work the same for Chrome and Edge, am I right to say that?

Comment: @AlanDávalos I have tried using the webcomponentjs-loader for other projects that I couldn't get it to work. I have another question posted on stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56334637/how-to-fix-web-components-not-showing-in-microsoft-edge)

Comment: *"it's a little bit confusing"* - From your response I gather you are in the learning phase, so would say you are trying to learn too many things at once . Best way is to stick with one Browser (Chrome or Firefox) ► Take a month getting familiar with [all Custom Elements concepts and syntax](https://www.dannymoerkerke.com/blog/web-components-will-replace-your-frontend-framework) and then worry about other Browsers. IMHO you should start with native JavaScript, only add LIT into the mix once you understand the basics.

Comment: Where'd you get these cdnjs URLs? We've never documented these as a supported method of loading the polyfills, so I'm unsure if they work. Also, we highly recommend use the webcomponents-loader as it only downloads the polyfills if needed.

Comment: Also, you're using an old version of LitElement. We moved the package from `@polymer/lit-element` to just `lit-element`. The old package name is not receiving any updates.

Answer (score 1):

This works in current versions of Edge, but I can see your problem if I load up an old version (though I get a nag to upgrade first). This version of Edge is *extremely* niche - it has less use than IE11 now.

However, your issue isn't a bug with the polyfills at all - they're loading fine. The problem is that you're using the wrong path for Lit.

If I switch that to the correct one it works fine in Edge 44:

[image: Fixed in Edge 44]

Here's a fixed fork of your Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/r5PNsGakMZK4JDMn

```
// todo-view.js line 1:
-- import { LitElement, html } from "https://unpkg.com/@polymer/lit-element/lit-element.js?module"; 
++ import { LitElement, html } from "https://unpkg.com/lit-element/lit-element.js?module";
```